# Cutting data appended to a .jpg file and save as mpg file

Tags: image, python-3.x

The background of my problem is that I want to extract the video data of Motion Photos (taken by my Samsung S7). Manually it is easy but time consuming. Just open the .jpg file in a HexEditor and extract all data after the line "MotionPhoto_Data". The first part is the image and the second part is the video.

My current code is

```
im = 'test.jpg'  

with open(im, 'rb') as fin:
    data = fin.read()
    data_latin = data.decode('latin1')
    fin.close()

position = data_latin.find('MotionPhoto_Data')

data_pic = data[:position]
data_mpg = data[position:]
```

My problem now is that I can´t figure out how to save these strings in a way that `data_pic` is saved as a working jpg and `data_mpg` as a working video.

I tried

```
with open('test_pic.jpg', 'a') as fin:
    fin.write(str(data_pic))
    fin.close()
```

But this didn´t worked. I think there is a basic issue on how I try to handle/save my data but I can´t figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use python 3 as it is tagged that way.

You should not decode with 'data.decode('latin1'). It is binary data.

```
data = fin.read()
```

Then later write it also as binary data:

```
with open('test_pic.jpg', 'ab') as fout:
    fout.write(data_pic)
    fout.close()
```

Comment: Now that I read it again, you shouldn't use a "fout.close()" when using a "with" statement. It is confusing as the "with" statements is precisely to avoid having to use "close" function.